# Android display only last added marker when try to add multiple markers

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to add multiple markers in my app. I have used following method to add markers to the map when it's called using recycleradapter but my problem is map is only showing lastly added marker.

```
public void createMarker(String lat, String lon) {
    LatLng location = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(lat), Double.valueOf(lon));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_custom_marker)));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location));
}
```

this is the recyclerAdapter code,

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final SearchPlaceRecycleAdapter.SearchPlaceRowHolder searchPlaceRowHolder, final int position) {
    final Place item = mSearchResultList.get(position);
    if (item != null) {
        if (PlaceFragment.placeFragment != null) {
            if ((item.getLat() != null && !item.getLat().isEmpty())
                    && (item.getLon() != null && !item.getLon().isEmpty())) {
                PlaceFragment.placeFragment.createMarker(item.getLat(), item.getLon());
            }
        }
    }
```

But it is not working fine. I am getting only one marker on the screen.

Comment: Please show us the code that calls this method.

Comment: This method is called using RecycleAdapter

Comment: share your rest of the  code

Comment: I have edited my question with recyclerAdapter code